# Google map api - How to Get the Place's Name from lat/lng

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Greetings i was searching for hours and I haven't found anything remotely close to this.

I am trying to use `Distance Matrix API`, However as an input the api needs the Origin `Address` aka `Name` and `Destination` as well. But i can only provide Origin's Lat/Lng and Destination's Lat/Lng from which i get them using my own `markers`.

Is it possible to get the place's Name and Address from Lat/Lng of the given origin? 
Or Am i in whole wrong path to achieve this? any suggestion would be appreciated. thank you.

Comment: check my explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the latitude/longitude coordinates for origin and destination parameters. Its in the documentation https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

But if you really want to get the address from latlng you can reverse geocode it like this:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

here is the link to the documentation for your reference
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start

Answer (score 1):

For your information. DistanceMatric Api works not only with string addresses it also works with lat/lng, place_id as well. 
Go through below doc
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

**So, no need to convert your lat,lng to string addresses.(otherwise simply api hits will increase)**

If you want to see result. Check below api.
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=40.6655101,-73.89188969999998&destinations=40.6905615%2C-73.9976592&key=[API_KEY]

Note: Replace API_KEY with your api key